# Showing certain div when certain image gets dynamically loaded with a lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

The Chocolate lightbox (http://chocolat.insipi.de/) is loading images in a container div. I would like to show another div with text concerning the image together with the image itself. Something like this (apart from that it doesn't work):

```
if ($('.chocolat-content').has('img[src="fotos/milkyway.jpg"]')) {
            $('#beauty').hide('fast')
            $('#milkyway').fadeIn()
} 
else if($('.chocolat-content').has('img[src="fotos/beauty.jpg"]')) {
            $('#milkyway').hide('fast')
            $('#beauty').fadeIn()
}
```

It probably has something to do with the script not knowing when a certain image is loaded...

Comment: Does it really have to be a different div element, or do you maybe just want to provide a caption for your images?

Comment: _“It probably has something to do with the script not knowing when a certain image is loaded...”_ - if you need to hook into that, the plugin provides some specific events, `afterImageLoad` could help perhaps.

Comment: @Cbroe: yes, a different div element.
I'll try the plugin you mentioned...

Comment: nope, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but using afterImageLoad always loads the first div, regardless of the src of the image...

Comment: Of course inside your handler function for that event, you will have to figure out which image is currently shown. https://github.com/nicolas-t/Chocolat/blob/master/readme.md#methods lists `current` at the very end, so by that you should bee able to get the index of the image currently shown. If you pass that index on to jquery's `.eq()`, you can easily get the corresponding image from your container element. Read the id of the element you want to fade in from for example a custom data attribute you set on the image, hide all such text elements first and then fade that specific element in.

Comment: I am actually not a programmer. Is it possible you could give me an example how to use this current method? That would be awesome!

Comment: I now have the following code to initialize the lightbox:

`    $('#gallery').Chocolat({
    container      : '#container2',
    imageSize     : 'contain',
    setTitle : '',
     loop:true,
    }).data('chocolat').api().open(); `

Comment: this one doesn't work:
    var instance = $('#gallery').Chocolat().data('chocolat');

    if(instance.api().current(0))
    {
        {$('#milkyway').fadeIn()}
    }
    if(instance.api().current(1))
    {
        {$('#beauty').fadeIn()}
    }

Comment: The documentation is rather sparse, but I don’t think calling this function with a parameter makes sense; this is most like simply returning the current image index. `var currentImgIndex = instance.api().current();`

Comment: It doesn't work:

 var currentImgIndex = instance.api().current();

    if(currentImgIndex == 0) {
        $('#milkyway').fadeIn()
    }
    if(currentImgIndex == 1) {
        $('#milkyway').hide('fast')
        $('#beauty').fadeIn()
    }
It shows #milkyway and it keeps on showing that.
I still think the script doesn't know what the current image will be when clicking the next or previous arrow...
It needs something that listens for when a certain image has been loaded in the container...But I have no clue how to do that...

Comment: Here is an example: https://www.wideopenwindows.be/test.html

Comment: Problem is you're executing that code only once there, so yes, you need to get this executed upon some event happening. Try this, and then watch in the browser console, what happens when you navigate through the image ... `instance.api().set('afterImageLoad', function() { console.log(instance.api().current())
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is an example: https://www.wideopenwindows.be/test.html

Let me pick up from there, this is getting a little to much for comments ...

Problem is you're executing that code only once there, so yes, you need to get this executed upon some event happening. Try this, and then watch in the browser console, what happens when you navigate through the images ...

```
instance.api().set('afterImageLoad', function() { 
  console.log(instance.api().current())
});
```

So that's gotten us the index of the currently displayed image. Now as I said, I would probably just put the id of the element you want to show directly onto the link element via a data attribute,

```
<a data-captionelement="beauty" class="chocolat-image" href="..."
```

We got the index of the currently showing image inside the #gallery container, but since that contains nothing else but just one image wrapped into one link each, that means image index and link index are the same, so we can select the link via the index directly.

Lets mash that all together ...

```
instance.api().set('afterImageLoad', function() { 
  var index = instance.api().current(),
      captionElementId = $('#gallery a') // get all the links in container
                           .eq(index) // get the one that contains current image
                           .data('captionelement'); // get id from data attibute

  $('.caption').hide(); // hide all caption elements; use whatever selector fits
                        // your document structure here

  $('#'+captionElementId).fadeIn(); // fade in the one we we're looking for
});
```

Now this is untested, but should give you the general idea. If it doesn't work immediately, please check console for whatever syntax errors might have crept in; if you can't get it to work please set up a https://jsfiddle.net/ example, and I'll have a look.